# How is the no-cloning theorem equivalent to the fact that two non-orthogonal states cannot be distinguished between in one measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I have seen a few isolated proofs for each of the above claims, but do not really see their 'if and only if' interdependence.

Answer (score 1):

First, assume you are given one of two states. If you can clone, you can use unambiguous state discrimination (i.e. a measurement with 3 outcomes: (i) must be state 1, (ii) must be state 2, (iii) not sure) to make copies and measure until you get one of the two unambiguous outcomes (i) or (ii), thereby distinguishing the two states.

Conversely, if you want to clone an unknown state which is in one of two non-orthogonal states, you can use a measurement which allows to distinguish them to identify which state you have, and then make copies of it.

Whether the converse also allows to derive a general cloner for a completely unkown quantum state from the ability to just distinguish *two* copies: Probably not in such a straightforward fashion.  On a deeper level, they both lead to violations of linearity, and then pretty much anything will be possible.